# Basic algebra operations on known size arrays

Tags: c++, numeric

I am a newbie c++ developper transitionning from Fortran.
I am trying to write **the most efficient** possible function to compute the norm of the difference of two compile-time known size std::arrays (typically between 1 and 10, most often < 100). Of course, a simple for-loop easily does the trick, but I wonder how it compares (in terms of efficiency) to more modern style of programming, (possibly using std::accumulate, or std::inner_product ?).

Maybe a simple solution already exists in a dedicated library (like Boost or Eigen) ? I understand too little of those to make sure.

Best,

Comment: You have to measure to be sure, but I would say they should be equivalent.

Comment: If you are wondering then the next step is to try these alternatives and time them. There really is no generally applicable answer to questions about efficiency.

Comment: the standard algorithms usually dont perform worse than a handwritten code. The deal is: awesome abstractions for zero overhead. It is **not**: automagically your code gets faster

Comment: Depending on the problem (and the platform you want to solve it on), you can gain some speed by parallelising. Many standard algorithms allow parallelisation via [execution policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) (e. g. [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)), you might use these for. If you find nothing appropriate, there are parallelisation libraries like [Open MP](https://www.openmp.org/).

Comment: Something not mentioned yet, if your arrays are filled (or can be filled) at compile time, you can use `constexpr` to calculate this kind of thing then (no runtime cost!). You will have to write your own function for this as the standard ones are not yet constexpr. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157731/compile-time-equivalent-to-stdaccumulate for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both hand-written loops and standard algorithms will most likely result in the same code. In any case, I would not expect a meaningful performance difference on a reasonable compiler.

The real performance gain here will have to come from vectorization.

- Auto-vectorization varies very strongly between compilers (and may be off by default for floating point operations because those are not associative). In theory, using standard algorithms with the `std::execution::parallel_unsequenced_policy` (or `std::execution::unsequenced_policy` in C++20) should hint to the compiler that they can/should vectorize the loop code, but compiler adoption of this is low at the moment.
- You could hand-write the vectorized code, but that may be tricky to get good/right. It's certainly not a productive investment of your time unless you know the section is performance-critical.
- Some libraries may already have properly vectorized code for such operations. I would expect `Eigen` and possibly <s>[`ublas`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52738776/9528746)</s>, `armadillo` or `lapack` to have this figured out. But you would have to check them yourself and whether they do what you need for your given platform.

As always: If you care about performance, measure and compare. There is no universal answer.

Comment: Mmh. I actually did not even think about vectorization. Thanks for the tip.